# code below require_once does not execute

Tags: php, echo, require-once

I have following code, however $email is not getting printed on page. I don't know why.

```
<?php


    $email = "myemil@gmail.com";        
    $tag = "login";

    require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    echo $email; 
?>
```

If I remove

> require_once 'DB_Functions.php'; $db = new DB_Functions();

then it prints email on page. Why is this happening? I want to connect to DB. Please help.

Above code file is on godaddy server, in a subdomain.

DB_Functions.php looks like

> class DB_Functions {
>
> ```
> private $db;
>  function __construct() {
>     require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
>     $this->db = new DB_Connect();
>     $this->db->connect();
> }
>
> function __destruct() {
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

DB_Connect looks like

> class DB_Connect {
>
> ```
> // constructor
> function __construct() {
>
> }
>
> // destructor
> function __destruct() {
>     // $this->close();
> }
>
> // Connecting to database
> public function connect() {
>     require_once 'config.php';
>     // connecting to mysql
>     $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
>     // selecting database
>     mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
>
>     // return database handler
>     return $con;
> }
>
> // Closing database connection
> public function close() {
>     mysql_close();
> }
> ```
>
> }

config.php

> define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
>   define("DB_USER", "db1");
>   define("DB_PASSWORD", "db1"); 
>   define("DB_DATABASE", "db1");

Comment: *Above code file is on godaddy server, in a subdomain.* You are not specifying any subdomain in your path.

Comment: @1nflktd I did not get you. What do you specifying subdomain?

Comment: The file `DB_Functions.php` is inside the same dir that the file you are requiring it in ?

Comment: Yes. All files are in the same directory. And I am not getting any error. Just blank page is displayed.

Comment: Do you have error_reporting on ?

Comment: Add these lines at the beginning of your file:
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: @GershomMaes thanks. Adding those lines helped me to get error. I solved it.